# Fetch the latest changes from main branch

Tags: git

I create a `test` branch from `main` branch and start working on it,but then my team push the changes to mainline of the package.So How can I update the `main` branch with the new changes that is push by my teammate, then How can I also update my `test` branch with those changes.

Comment: Git pull origin main
Git pull origin test

Comment: Are you using `git bash` or a Git UI?

Comment: Refer to these links https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 4):

In your setup `main` is a non-current branch. (Unlike other answers) There is a simple way to update a non-current branch without switching to it:

```
git fetch origin main:main
```

After that merge `main` into the current `test` using `git merge main`. Or rebase `test` on top of the updated `main`:

```
git rebase main test
```

If you prefer merge you can do everything in one command:

```
git pull origin main:main
```

This command does `git fetch origin main:main` and then `git merge main` at once.

With rebase there are two commands:

```
git fetch origin main:main
git rebase main test
```

Most probably they can be combined in one command to fetch, update and rebase:

```
git pull --rebase origin main:main
```

Comment: @TTT But you need to update `main` somehow. `git rebase origin/main main && git rebase main test` ?

Comment: @TTT I think you can write a separate detailed answer about it.

Comment: This is a better answer to this question than mine would be. :D

Comment: I propose we clean up this banter. ;)

Comment: @TTT BTW `git pull --rebase origin main:main` is just one command to fetch, update and rebase.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you have committed all the changes in your current branch

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Some clear commit message"
```

2. Go to your main branch, fetch the remote changes and merge to your local `main` branch

```
git checkout main
git pull origin main
```

3. Now go back to your local `test` branch and **merge** those changes with the `main` branch

```
git checkout test
git merge main
```

4. That's it. If there are no conflicts, branches will be merged automatically. Otherwise, read carefully the prompted message and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to back-merge main branch again after updating it on your local:

```
 git checkout main
 git pull origin main
 git checkout test
 git merge main
 git push
```